# Can't paste magic code in Teams bot channel

Tags: botframework

Backround:
We are using .NET SDK Version 3.13.1.0 of the bot framework on azure as azure webapp.

During the authentication process I get magic number which I have to paste in the Teams conversion. The problem is when I'm using "copy paste" I get authentication error.
I came across this [Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4768) where this problem is mentioned as bug but  I couldn't find any solution.

Anyone familiar with this issue ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what exactly does it look like when you paste it? Is it the EXACT same code, or has it added extra characters?

Comment: It's the exact same code.  
The team channel support different kind of font size. When I paste the code Teams keep the original font size as it seems in the browser. When I type the code it uses the default font size of Teams. Teams adds characters to the message for the other side to know the font size and this is what causing the problem.

Comment: My question is - is this known bug ? How can I deal with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in the Teams channel [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4768), where magic codes cannot be copy-pasted, possibly due to the aforementioned font issue. Possible work arounds include attempting to copy-'paste as plain text', pasting into a notepad-like program (strips the rich text from the copy), or manually typing it out.